# Is it possible to add a breakpoint without debug symbols?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

Let's say I have a release build of a .NET DLL that was built in Release mode without debug symbols. This DLL is called from unmanaged code and I can attach to the process running it using Debug/Attach to Process.

**Is it possible to add a breakpoint when, for example, some specific method is entered?** I'm aware that I won't have source code and won't be able to step through the application, I just want execution to stop at that point to investigate the system state in the immediate window. Since "method names" are available to the .NET runtime even in Release Builds, I assume that this should be possible *somehow*.

What I've tried:

- *Debug/New Breakpoint/Break at Function.* Does not break, probably due to missing symbols.
- Hit *Break All* in the tool bar. This breaks, but the Immediate Window says `Unable to evaluate the expression` for every expression, probably due to the fact that no managed code is executing at the moment.

Comment: can we call Debug.Break()

Comment: Technically, yes, you can set breakpoints on the generated machine code.  That's however incredibly painful, massive needle-in-the-haystack problem.  Starting with the needle not being there yet, the code isn't generated until the method is called so getting it to break on the first call is close to impossible.  Blind as a bat as well after it breaks, you'll have to reverse engineer stack locations and register values back to arguments and local variables.  It just isn't worth it.  Beg, steal or borrow the PDB files, they are just way too easy to generate.

Comment: @HansPassant: Makes sense, thanks for the detailed explanation! I'll leave the question option, though, since I'm still curious *how* to set a breakpoint in such a case (breaking on a non-first call would be sufficient).